# How can I animate with jQuery before loading next page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, href

I want to add an animation that will run when a user clicks a link, but *before* the linked page begins to load. Whenever I try this, the page begins to load immediately and the animation only gets about halfway through before the next page is up.

If I add `return false` to the end of the javascript block, the next page never loads. How can I do this?

Comment: Hey "vote-to-close"ers: Why is the question not about programming? This looks like any other reasonable question here.

Comment: Because you need to show some code.

Comment: Yeah, but it wasn't a real question per se... it was an "answer your own questions community wiki style". The question was just a way to explain the answer...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to first remove the native click action for the appropriate `<a>` element. So:

```
 $('#mainNavigation a').on('click',function(){
    return false;
    });
```

Then add an animation to the click event of those `<a>` elements. End the animation by sending the user to the linked page. Make sure you only send the user to the next page *after* the animation is complete by putting the `window.location` statement inside the animation callback function.

```
$('#mainNavigation a').click(function(){

    // get the link url
    loc = $(this).attr('href');

    // run the animation
    $('#logo').animate({width:'100%',height:121},800,function(){
        window.location = loc;
        });


    });
```

Alternatively, use `event.preventDefault()` in the block above instead of the first 3 lines in this answer. *Thanks [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18796/ian-mclaird)!*

Comment: Is there any reason you have to remove the native click handler?  Won't `event.preventDefault()` do the trick?

Comment: Ah, yes I suppose so. I didn't know that one. And to think I struggled with this for so long....grrr.

Comment: And note that jQuery `.live()` is already deprecated. Use `.on()` instead. http://api.jquery.com/live/